# CSS to wrap contents in stylized container?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have a stylesheet that specifies a style for `<LABEL>`.

But some `<LABEL>`s are special: Currently I inline style them like this:

```
<LABEL style="text-align:right; line-height:15pt">
    <div style="padding-right:20px">My Label Text</div>
</LABEL>
```

I suspect there's a way to specify a CSS class, perhaps called `rightlabel`, to render the preceding using something simple like this:

```
<LABEL class="rightlabel">My Label Text</LABEL>
```

What would the correct way be to do that?  I.e., is there a way to define `rightlabel` in CSS to produce the overridden `<LABEL>` **while automatically wrapping its children in a padded child container** (because the style doesn't work correctly unless that is done, and it doesn't seem proper to depend on the coder to implement two elements to get the style right)?

**Amendment:**  I can get most of the way there using a child selector – as shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3h9a2b9/) with this CSS:

```
.rightLabel {text-align: right}
.rightLabel > * {padding-right: 20px}
```

But I can't find a way to apply the padding to the label contents without explicitly wrapping the contents in some container.  I.e., the above CSS works correctly on

```
<LABEL class="rightLabel">
  <div>This is what we wanted!</div>
</LABEL>
```

but not on

```
<LABEL class="rightLabel">Why am I not padded?</LABEL>
```

Is it possible to apply a style to the `<LABEL>` contents without explicitly coding them inside another HTML element (child)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your styles like so:

```
<style> 
.rightLabel
{
    text-align:right;
}

.rightLabel div 
{
    padding-right:20px;
}
</style>
```

Update to updated question: you can't add a div using CSS, you'll need JavaScript. You can add pseudo elements using :before and :after.

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c3h9a2b9/1/

```
.rightLabel:before {
  display:block;
  content:' ';
  width:20px;
  float:right;
}
```

This fakes the padding by using the `:before` or `:after` pseudo element on your label. It needs a display of block (inline-block would also do) and some dimensions, the width here being 20px (the "padding" that you need) and floated in the direction you want padding....

Comment: Is it possible to automatically wrap the `LABEL` contents in a DIV with that style, so the coder doesn't have to remember to?  I.e., using this solution the style "fails" if one doesn't remember to wrap the child in a div and apply the same class.

Comment: It is an example of how to define your styles, as per your question. Maybe you need to rethink your HTML build structure if your unsure at this early stage..?

Comment: Perhaps.  I just updated the question to try to make it clear why I think this is a problem.  If the solution is to do the HTML differently by all means please explain!

Comment: It doesn't have to be a DIV.  It's just that the label contents have to be kept 20px from the right edge of the label.  It *seems* like pseudo- or child-selectors or something should be able to do that, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed! Now it is clear what you are trying to achieve, experiment with using pseudo selectors :before and :after on your label elements.

Comment: It can be done with a child selector -- see https://jsfiddle.net/c3h9a2b9/ -- but that still requires that the label text be explicitly wrapped in a subcontainer.

Comment: I've an updated fiddle for you, https://jsfiddle.net/c3h9a2b9/1/  You can fake the padding using this technique, and it doesn't involve the extra div in the markup, as per your requirements.  The idea is to give the pseudo element block display and some dimensions, 20px wide in this case, and float it in the direction you want your "padding"...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question the answer is this CSS:

```
label{
    //Your general label style
}
label.rightlabel{
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 15pt;
}
label.rightlabel div{
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

With this HTML should act as you wish

```
<label>a normal label</label>
</label class="right label"><div>the special label</div></label>
```

This works because more specific CSS overrides less specific one by default :)

Comment: That's half of it.  But the label text won't be properly padded unless it is contained in a child element with the specified padding.  Can that be applied automatically via CSS?